# React native app link business page to facebook messenger

Tags: facebook, react-native

Im trying to open facebook messenger from react native app using Linking to business page.
I succeed to do that for user

```
Linking.openURL(`fb-messenger://user/1000XXXXXXXXX`)
```

but for business page such [this page](https://www.facebook.com/sport24live/)

I tried this way

```
   Linking.openURL(`fb-messenger://user//sport24live`)
```

or

```
   Linking.openURL(`fb-messenger://sport24live`)
```

and it's not working, not open anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook has added m.me links which is a shortened URL that redirects to a person, page or a bot in messenger.

Therefore you can use it as

```
Linking.openURL(`http://m.me/sport24live`)
```

Check out more in the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links)

Comment: exactly what I'm looking for, thanks. I'll have to wait 24 hours to give you the points :-)